# Convert color to RRRGGGBBB

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, rgb, ini

Currently rewriting an .ini file of an existing program. This .ini file contains rgb values.

Now I am changing the rgb values but the problem is that the existing program only reads the value if both the r, g and b values have 3 numbers.

For example, if I write down the rgb value it says: 255,0,0 or 0,0,225. The only way the existing program is able to read the rgb values is if they are wrote down like this: 255,000,000 or 000,000,255.

The code I use to write down the rgb values:

```
Byte[] SeatL1 = new UTF8Encoding(true)
               .GetBytes("L1=" + r2.BackColor.R.ToString() + 
                         ", " + r2.BackColor.G.ToString() + 
                         ", " + r2.BackColor.B.ToString());
fsNew.Write(SeatL1, 0, SeatL1.Length);
```

Is there a simple way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Byte[] SeatL1 = new UTF8Encoding(true)
           .GetBytes("L1=" + r2.BackColor.R.ToString("000") + 
                     ", " + r2.BackColor.G.ToString("000") + 
                     ", " + r2.BackColor.B.ToString("000"));
fsNew.Write(SeatL1, 0, SeatL1.Length);
```